# Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat throwing error in vs code while installing

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've set up my vs code for java. But while installing **Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat** extension it is giving an error. Here is the log message:

```
[2021-03-22 23:31:42.665] [renderer1] [error] An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.
[2021-03-23 00:06:53.635] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at G.downloadInstallableExtension (file:///F:/Programming/Softwares/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:47:212029)
    at async G.doInstallFromGallery (file:///F:/Programming/Softwares/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:47:209233)
```

Then I downloaded it manually and tried to install but error happend again. Here is the log:

```
[2021-03-23 00:31:32.133] [renderer1] [error] invalid comment length. expected: 3755. found: 0: Error: invalid comment length. expected: 3755. found: 0
    at S (file:///F:/Programming/Softwares/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:47:192087)
    at file:///F:/Programming/Softwares/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:47:193482
    at F:\Programming\Softwares\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\yauzl\index.js:37:7
    at F:\Programming\Softwares\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\yauzl\index.js:133:16
    at F:\Programming\Softwares\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\yauzl\index.js:631:5
    at F:\Programming\Softwares\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\fd-slicer\index.js:32:7
    at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:524:5)
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to download a ZIP file and that file didn't download correctly.

Comment: But i downloaded it manually,, then it also gives an error

Comment: Then the zip file is corrupt.  Can you open it in WinZip?

Comment: What's your vscode version? Does this error occurred when you install other extensions, like **Debugger for Java**? and have you tried deleting the downloaded extension completely, then reinstall it?

Comment: My vs code version :1.54.3,,  yes some other java relates extensions are giving error,, and also i cant unzip manually downloaded extension cause it is in vsix formate.

Answer (score 0):

I searched in vscode-java and found [the similar issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/246), there's a [workaround](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/246#issuecomment-312356451) raised, which is downloading the latest java-*.vsix file and follow the instruction [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix).

Besides, change the downloaded packages to `.zip` as extensions, then unzip and reinstall it. See if the question goes away.